# ESP32 + Fastled + WS2801

Tags: esp32, led-strip

I'm using the ESP32 DevkitC board with Fastlib and a WS2801 LED strip.
The LED strips works fine, i connected it properly (sometimes all LEDs are on, no flickering).

I Connected the light strip's Data cable (blue) to GPIO16 and Clock cable (red) to GPIO17.
Compiling works but at first shows this error:

```
"No hardware SPI pins defined.  All SPI access will default to bitbanged output"
```

When the script starts, only the first 3 LEDs are glowing in light blue (instead of blinking) - here's my code:

```
#include <FastLED.h>

// How many leds in your strip?
#define NUM_LEDS 42

// For led chips like Neopixels, which have a data line, ground, and power, you just
// need to define DATA_PIN.  For led chipsets that are SPI based (four wires - data, clock,
// ground, and power), like the LPD8806 define both DATA_PIN and CLOCK_PIN
#define DATA_PIN 16
#define CLOCK_PIN 17

// Define the array of leds
CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

void setup() { 
      // Uncomment/edit one of the following lines for your leds arrangement.
      // FastLED.addLeds<TM1803, DATA_PIN, RGB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
      // FastLED.addLeds<TM1804, DATA_PIN, RGB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
      // FastLED.addLeds<TM1809, DATA_PIN, RGB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
      // FastLED.addLeds<WS2811, DATA_PIN, RGB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
      // FastLED.addLeds<WS2812, DATA_PIN, RGB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
      // FastLED.addLeds<WS2812B, DATA_PIN, RGB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
      // FastLED.addLeds<NEOPIXEL, DATA_PIN>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
      // FastLED.addLeds<APA104, DATA_PIN, RGB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
      // FastLED.addLeds<UCS1903, DATA_PIN, RGB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
      // FastLED.addLeds<UCS1903B, DATA_PIN, RGB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
      // FastLED.addLeds<GW6205, DATA_PIN, RGB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
      // FastLED.addLeds<GW6205_400, DATA_PIN, RGB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);

      // FastLED.addLeds<WS2801, RGB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
      // FastLED.addLeds<SM16716, RGB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
      // FastLED.addLeds<LPD8806, RGB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
      // FastLED.addLeds<P9813, RGB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
      // FastLED.addLeds<APA102, RGB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
      // FastLED.addLeds<DOTSTAR, RGB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);

       FastLED.addLeds<WS2801, DATA_PIN, CLOCK_PIN, RGB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
      // FastLED.addLeds<SM16716, DATA_PIN, CLOCK_PIN, RGB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
      // FastLED.addLeds<LPD8806, DATA_PIN, CLOCK_PIN, RGB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
      // FastLED.addLeds<P9813, DATA_PIN, CLOCK_PIN, RGB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
      // FastLED.addLeds<APA102, DATA_PIN, CLOCK_PIN, RGB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
      // FastLED.addLeds<DOTSTAR, DATA_PIN, CLOCK_PIN, RGB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
}

void loop() { 
  // Turn the LED on, then pause
  leds[0] = CRGB::Red;
  FastLED.show();
  delay(500);
  // Now turn the LED off, then pause
  leds[0] = CRGB::Black;
  FastLED.show();
  delay(500);
}
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is hard to debug from afar...

Your sketch looks correct (hardly surprising, since it's just the Blink example). But I'd try to use IO18/SPI_CLK for clock and IO23/SPI_MOSI for data, as these are the hardware SPI pins of the ESP32. It might very well be that using these pins removes the warning about hardware SPI.

As I don't know all the variants of a WS2801 strip... is it maybe one of those strips that runs at 12V and can only be cut every three LEDs? This would explain why there are three LEDs lighting up instead of one (because then there would be one chip for three LEDs -- in other words, each "pixel" in your leds array corresponds to three physical LEDs)

Then there might be a problem with the voltage output of your ESP32 board. The ESP is running at Vcc=3.3V. The chips of the strip are running at Vcc=5V and expect 5V on their inputs. A logical 1 is assumed when the input in question is 0.7 * Vcc, i.e. the input signal may not be less than 3.3V. Now imagine that the power regulator on your ESP board drives the ESP at a teensy bit less (e.g. at 3.25V) and the power supply for the strip outputs a teensy bit more (e.g. 5.1V) -- suddenly, a logical 1 from the ESP is at 0.637 times the strips' Vcc and therefore in the undefined limbo between 0.3*Vcc (highest definition for logical 0) and 0.7*Vcc (lowest definition for logical 1). A level shifter module would help here to increase the ESP's output signal voltage (costs a few cents when ordered directly from China).

Then, at last, are you sure that the color order of the strip is RGB (as stated in your setup line)? I've seen more strips using GRB or BGR... which would explain why you see blue instead of red.